# Updating Encryption Algorithm failed for Apache Nifi "Decryption Failed with Algorithm [AES/GCM/NoPadding]"

Tags: encryption, apache-nifi

After upgrading Nifi, the following warning was logged when starting Nifi:

WARN [Flow Service Tasks Thread-2] d.o.a.n.s.u.c.NiFiLegacyCipherProvider Insecure Cipher Provider Algorithm [PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL] generate salt requested

This did not affect the function of Nifi. Its annoying So I followed the following resources, which seemed simple enough:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#updating-the-sensitive-properties-algorithm
https://exceptionfactory.com/posts/2021/07/29/deciphering-apache-nifi-component-property-encryption/#setting-the-sensitive-properties-algorithm

However, after trying multiple paths, I always got the following error message when restarting Nifi:

Decryption Failed with Algorithm [AES/GCM/NoPadding]
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: mac check in GCM failed